# How can I put different elements of array in different cells of a table?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, cells

For example I have got an array `[1 2 1 1 1 1 ]`. Now I want to set this in different cells of a table

As shown in code I would like to put `[1 2 1 1 1 1]` in this table.

```
class datatablenew extends JFrame {

  private   JPanel      topPanel;
  private   JTable      table;
  private   JScrollPane scrollPane;

  public datatablenew() {
    setTitle("dynamic data");
    setSize(300, 200);
    setBackground(Color.gray);

    // Create a panel to hold all other components
    JPanel datapanel = new JPanel();
    datapanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    getContentPane().add(datapanel);



    // Create columns names

    String rowData[]={"row 1","row 2","row 3"};

    String columnname[]={"column 1","column 2","column3"};

    // Create some data
    String dataValues[][] =
        {
            { "", "", "" },
            { "", "", "" },
            { "", "", "" },
            { "", "", "" }
        };


    // Create a new table instance


    table =new JTable(dataValues,columnname);
    table=new JTable(dataValues,rowData);

    Add the table to a scrolling pane

        scrollPane=new JScrollPane(table);
    datapanel.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }

}
```

Comment: `String dataValues[][] = {{ 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1 }};`?

Comment: Do you want the values from the array in the JTable initially or are you looking for a way to change the contents of the JTable later (after the datatablenew constructor has been called)? Should the array be divided over two rows of three columns, or should the number of columns be increased to six?